outline vpn подтягивает имя хоста из nginx
Имеется сервер ubuntu 22.04.03

На нем установлен outline server
nginx

На nginx работает 1 сайт, конфиг/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.ru
server {

        root /var/www/example.ru/html;
        index index.html index.htm app.js index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.ru www.example.ru;

        location / {
                 try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location /demo {
                rewrite ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
                try_files $uri /demo/index.html @clean_url;
        }

        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = example.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.ru www.example.ru;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

Outline работает на порту 19308, когда я подключаюсь по vpn и проверяю свой ip на сайте myip.ru Имя хоста выдает example.ru
если я правильно это из-за настройки конфига nginx, но не понимаю, как это обойти, чтобы сайт работал корректно но при подключении к outline имя хоста был ip адрес сервера, а не название сайта

myip.ru выдаёт имя хоста из PTR-записи, и это не имеет никакого отношения к nginx

В этом случае, если я поменяю PTR Запись, то у меня могут начаться проблемы с сайтом/почтой на нем?
решения это  - отдельный vds?
